# How can I use Poermock mocking local a variable?

Tags: powermock

I'm using Powermock to mock local variable "response" in sendAddTaskResult method.

```java
public void sendAddTaskResult() {
//....
HttpResponse response 
    = request.header("Authorization", "Token " + token).fields(parameters).asJson();
//....
}
```

this is my mocking code:

```java
HttpResponse httpResponse=mock(HttpResponse.class);
when(httpResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);
whenNew(HttpResponse.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(httpResponse);
```

It seems doesn't work, I wish someone would help me，Thanks！

---

Thanks for [mksmanjit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5137530/mksmanjit) answer, I tried to mock HttpResponse, and use Powermock "whenNew" method to mock HttpRequestWithBody, but it seems my mock "HttpRequestWithBody" doesn't work properly. It can't work during create HttpRequestWithBody object...

```java
//mock HttpResponse
HttpResponse httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
when(httpResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(200);

//mock HttpRequestWithBody
HttpRequestWithBody httpRequestWithBody =mock(HttpRequestWithBody.class);
when(httpRequestWithBody.header(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(httpRequestWithBody);
when(httpRequestWithBody.header(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()).fields(anyParameters())).thenReturn(mock(MultipartBody.class));
when(httpRequestWithBody.header(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString()).fields(anyParameters()).asJson()).thenReturn(httpResponse);

// mock new local variable 
whenNew(HttpRequestWithBody.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(httpRequestWithBody);
```

```java
private static Map<String, Object> anyParameters() {
    return Mockito.any();
}
```

Comment: HttpResponse  is returned from the request.asJson() method, Can you please check how HttpResponse object is created inside asJson(), or else you have to mock the request object(if possible) then call when(request.asJson()).thenReturn(mockedHttpResponse);

Comment: Please also check whether your added HttpResponse  in the @PrepareForTest({HttpResponse.class}) at the top of your test class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I try to test code with your suggestions , but it seems "whenNew" method doesn't work ...

Comment: Can you please share your Full code over GitHub if possible? So that I can check myself.